# Importing drag-sort-listview library in Android Studio gradle project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to import the drag-sort-listview android library into my application in Android Studio. I had no problems using it with Eclipse before.

Git repository for library: https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is to define the dependency on it in your `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'asia.ivity.android:drag-sort-listview-apklib:1.0@apklib'
}
```

Comment: This answer is outdated, see Edu Zamora's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Nowadays, you can just add the dependency in your `build.gradle` as:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'asia.ivity.android:drag-sort-listview:1.0'
}
```